# Hard Wired Man in the Middle Logging

Tags: man-in-the-middle, logging, arp-spoofing

I am wanting to set up a single logging point on my home network that logs URLs and search terms to monitor teenagers... um... activity.

I was thinking of setting up a computer between the cable modem and the router, which would capture all network traffic. The upside would be no need for arp spoofing, the downside would be you would lose specific device information for if the traffic was on a wireless tablet vs wired PC.

I have played with Kali a little, and while there are some cool things like driftnet, urlsnarf, and arpspoof, they all seem to be to target a single device, and seems most tutorials are for creating wireless hotspots.

With thousands of tools available, I am not sure where to start on this, where I am wanting basically a consolidated browser history from all devices on the network.

I have a PC with a 4 port GB network card and an SSD available with Kali installed. Is my plan of putting it between the router and modem good, or should I stick with arp spoofing past the router? The router is a Linksys 1200AC.

Comment: Do you have certificates installed on all the devices? You won't be able to extract anything besides the hostname if you can't decrypt the traffic.

Comment: I have access to all the devices I suppose. I haven't played with installing certificates, but as long as I can do it on Apple, Android, and Windows then I could do that.

Comment: You should probably just set up a Linux-based machine and use that for your router. That way you won't lose L2 information or need a second device. You'll need to make sure it's safe from the Internet, but I guess that's going to be easier than using some consumer router anyways.

Comment: I could use pfSense I guess, but then I loose wireless without secondary access points. Can I log the things I want using pfSense or other equivalent? Is Man in the Middle the correct terminology for what I am doing?

Comment: Yes, for decrypting the traffic you would perform a MITM attack. I've never used pfSense,  but I'm assuming that with enough configuration you can make it do whatever you want. I'm pretty sure pfSense is compatible with wireless adapters, so I'm not sure why you'd need secondary access points.

Comment: It's a 7000 sqft home, where I would put a full PC wouldn't have the same reach as where I would put the existing wireless router.

Comment: You'd probably want to use something like the (now dated) PC Engines APU, not a full blown desktop PC for the router. There are many small devices that are suitable for using as a router.

Comment: You can use a *nix computer as the actual router, and still use your existing wireless hardware for the access point itself.

Comment: What about going straight from the router to the Kali box, then to the 48 port switch? Not sure if that is the same as having it act as the router without actually needing to configure it as a router. I have a couple Ubiquiti access points, so I could turn off the wifi of the Linksys and still capture everything I would think.

Comment: As you mention Ubiquiti (and probably their UniFi line), you might want to just drop in a Syslog server [as described here](https://community.ui.com/questions/syslog-server-and-unifi-logs/bbde4318-e73f-4efe-b1b9-ae11319cc1d9) like Splunk – there are alternatives – and start there. When you know what you are searching for, you will have a base to ask the proper questions. Please keep in mind, that while the kids are teenagers, they still have rights. And this includes privacy. Locking down certain domains can be achieved without canons in your firewall/ USG as well.